# Layout Managers in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I'm kind of new to flash and i just can't find a nice way to control the position of the elements that i add to a container movie clip.

What i do is addChild to my target container Movie Clip and the control
the x,y values of the child depending on the total width and total height of 
all other children in the container. Awful.

Could you provide me with some diretions.

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Automatic positioning?

Comment: Yes if possible. In C# it would be something like flowlayout. In general i want either to use a ready made layout manager so that the result of addChild will not be just the default position resulting in overlapping children

Comment: Then have a look at Flex's layout system using `mxml`. There are controls like c# Stackpanel named `VBox` or `HBox`.

Comment: I ll have a look at that, sounds like exactly what i needed! thank you DanielB

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use those classes, easy to use, very helpfull :

http://www.greensock.com/liquidstage/
http://www.greensock.com/autofitarea/

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a slightly more involved layout engine; then you may wish to cast your eyes over the following projects:

- [AS3Commons UI](https://github.com/AS3Commons/as3commons-ui) - Lightweight and open source layout management. ([example](http://sibirjak.com/osflash/projects/as3commons-ui/layouts/showcase/))
- [Reflex](https://github.com/reflex/reflex-framework) - An pure AS3 alternative to the Flex Framework. ([example](http://reflex.io/?page_id=3))
- [ASwing](http://www.aswing.org/) - A port of the JSwing layout framework from the world of Java.